# iOS Adding conditional timer

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swiftui

I'm working on a `SwiftUI` app I have a `AnyView` that has a button to increase count and users can tap as many times as they want, every tap currently makes an api call I want to wait for 0.20 secs from `.now()` before I make the api call.

This is what I have tried so far,

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.20) { make the api call }
```

The issue I'm encountering currently this timer is being called all the time I'm tapping on the button with 0.20 secs.

For Example: 1 action was called in 0.1 sec I want to make an api call from 0.20 of that action but if another action was called before 0.20 sec I want to make call after 0.20 sec of it

button tapped -> wait 0.20 secs and make api call with count 1 as param but if button was tapped again make api call after 0.20 secs from that action and pass param as count 2.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the issue. You're saying "I want to wait for 0.20 secs from `.now()`", and it seems that this is what's going on. What do you mean "this timer is being called all the time I'm tapping on the button with 0.20 secs."? How does this not satisfy what you wanted?

Comment: @NewDev  I'm getting count on every tap of the button if user taps 3 times I'm making 3 calls, which is exactly what I want to avoid all I want to do is wait on making api call for 0.20 secs then make single call with final count i.e user quickly tapped 3 times within 0.20 secs I make single call after 0.20 sec with count 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to need is something like a debounce functionality. Combine has a debounce operator that might be suitable for this case.

The way it works is that it would wait a specified time interval after the last upstream value has arrived, which is exactly what you wanted timing-wise. What it doesn't do is keeping count of all the values that it debounced, so you'd need to keep an external counter.

So, let's say you have something like the following view model, which you can hook up to the button action in your view:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   private var counter = 0

   func makeTheApiCall() {
      // need to debounce here
   }
}
```

We can create a publisher that uses `.debounce` in its pipeline and increment/reset the counter accordingly:

```
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   private var counter = 0

   private let subject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
   private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

   init() {
      subject
         .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in self.counter += 1 })
         .debounce(for: .milliseconds(200), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
         .map { _ in self.counter }
         .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in self.counter = 0 })
         .sink { count in
             // make the actual api call here with the count of taps
             // since last api call
         }
         .store(in: &cancellables)
   }

   func makeTheApiCall() {
      subject.send()
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!!! this is exactly what I have been looking for

Comment: I'm getting compilation errors though "Value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'debounce'"

Comment: Missing parentheses... should be OK now @ArunKumar

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you disable the button right after it is clicked, and enable it only after the API call is made. That way, in the 0.2 seconds, another API call cannot be made.
`button.isEnabled = false`

Comment: In terms of requirement we cannot user stop from tapping that button but want to wait for 0.20 secs then make single call. I'm getting count on every tap if user taps 3 times I'm making 3 calls, all I want to do is wait on making api call for 0.20 secs then make single call with final count